# How can I insert data into product table that has attributes and categories contained in a different table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have the following tables

**product**

| product_id | product_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | 500 |
| 2 | bicycle | 100 |

**attribute**

| attribute_id | attribute_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Weight |
| 2 | Length |

**attribute_value**

**Note** :product_id column and attribute_column references the product and attribute table

| product_id | attribute_id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 |

My question is, how do I perform a SQL insert query that will add a new product and also add its attribute value to the **attribute_value table**

Comment: Just do an insert on the attribute_value table aswell with the attribute value? I don't see the problem here. Do you want it automatically added or something?

Comment: @ Swedo can you pls help out with the sample SQL code, I am new to MySQL

Comment: thanks so much, I thought I had to use a single insert statement and JOIN. I used multiple insert statements and it worked as desired.